# MySQL. Query out the amount of sales between two specific date intervals

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to write out a query with a category number, category name and the total sale for this category number between specific date intervals.

```
SELECT k.CatNr, k.name, lin.Price * lin.Number Totale_Sale
FROM kategori k, vare v, ordrelinje lin, ordre ord
WHERE k.CatNr = v.CatNr
AND v.VNr = lin.VNr
AND lin.OrderNr = ord.OrderNr
AND ord.Date BETWEEN 2011-01-14 AND 2011-01-15
GROUP BY k.Catnr;
```

The problem is that this does not return any expected values. I am especially unsure about the between part and need some advice on this to get it working. Thanks.

Comment: Is `ord.Date` a `DATE`, a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

- Date literals need single quotes: `'2011-01-14' AND '2011-01-15'`. Other wise, the engine thinks that you have numbers and substraction. `2011-01-14` is evaluated as the number `1996`.
- While `ord.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-14' AND '2011-01-15'` works when comparing `DATE` values, it will not work as expected if you have `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` columns/expressions. It's safer to use `>=` and `<`, like this:

  ```
     ord.Date >= '2011-01-14' AND ord.Date < '2011-01-15' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ```

  Read this article ***[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)*** for more explanations (the article is about SQL-Server but same principles apply to MySQL, regarding `BETWEEN` and date comparisons.)
- You group by one column `k.Catnr` but you use more columns in the `SELECT` list without aggregate functions. This is not standard ANSI/ISO SQL and will give you indeterminate results. If `k.Catnr` is (as suspected) the primary key of table `kategori`, you can skip putting `k.name` in the `GROUP BY` list but I suggest you do it anyway.

  For `lin.Price * lin.Number` though, I suspect you want the sum of those multiplications: `SUM(lin.Price * lin.Number)`
- Using implicit joins with the conditions in the `WHERE` list is old, very old syntax. The "new" (1992) syntax is to use the keyword `JOIN` which offers much more flexibility. Join conditions and restricting conditions are separated. There are many types of joins to choose (`LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `CROSS`, `NATURAL`) joins (and even `FULL` joins if you move to other DBMS that have them, not available in MySQL.) I strongly suggest you learn to use this syntax.
- You can use (or not) the keyword `AS` when defining aliases. This is up to you, if you prefer it or not. It's not mandatory.

After all the suggested changes, the query becomes:

```
SELECT 
    k.CatNr, 
    k.name, 
    SUM(lin.Price * lin.Number) AS Totale_Sale
FROM 
    kategori k
  JOIN 
    vare AS v
        ON k.CatNr = v.CatNr
  JOIN
    ordrelinje AS lin
        ON v.VNr = lin.VNr
  JOIN
    ordre AS ord
        ON lin.OrderNr = ord.OrderNr
WHERE 
    ord.Date >= '2011-01-14' 
  AND 
    ord.Date < '2011-01-15' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY 
    k.Catnr, 
    k.name ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advices!

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes `BETWEEN '2011-01-14' AND '2011-01-15'` and

> lin.Price * lin.Number **AS** Totale_Sale

```
SELECT k.CatNr, k.name, 
       lin.Price * lin.Number AS Totale_Sale
FROM kategori k, vare v, ordrelinje lin, ordre ord
WHERE k.CatNr = v.CatNr
AND v.VNr = lin.VNr
AND lin.OrderNr = ord.OrderNr
AND ord.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-14' AND '2011-01-15'
GROUP BY k.Catnr;
```